MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=59587) Max retry
I am using snowflake python API to connect to session.
from snowflake.core import Root

root = Root(session)

and I have the above max retry error.
That root helps me connect to snowpark and helps me schedule cron job.
It will also help me schedule sprocs and be able to run them using DAGs.
Also log models accordingly.

I was able to fix this issue by running the following command.
/Applications/Python\ 3.9/Install\ Certificates.command

